# register assembly in application page

Tags: application-pages, custom-control

I have created a custom Button with some extra properties. I want to register it in my Application Page like this

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Test1.Test2.Helpers" Assembly="Test1.Test2" TagPrefix="test" %>
```

But it casts an exception and saying something like it cannot find the assembly.

Comment: check this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3269a2e0-50c4-4404-8d30-75b2a654d8b7/sharepoint-application-pages-and-custom-server-control?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy the assembly to GAC and use the fully qualified Name in assembly tag as:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="MyControls" 
    Namespace="KM.MyControls.MyControl" 
    Assembly="KM.MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<Your token>" %>
```

Then you can reference your User Control

```
   <MyControls:MyUserControl runat="server"/>
```

Comment: It is same assembly which contains the application page so it must be GAC:ed ? and I just added a useul class which inherits from Button class

Comment: add the "Test1.Test2" assembly to GAC.

Comment: It is not User Control, It is a normal class which is derived from Button and it is in the same project that contains the Application Page (SharePoint Project) which is already GAC:ed

Comment: So just add fully qualified name to your assembly tag.